# Push notifications not received in some devices in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, ios8, apple-push-notifications

I am implementing the push notification in iOS for sending offers and deals. Right now I am working in the development environment. I see that some of the devices are not being notified. Could anybody explain possible causes? I have also read that if a push is sent to same device multiple times then APPLE disables them for that particular device? Could some one verify this or provide any documentation where I can find the issue. Any feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you just try a push service that are free and provide everything for you? Like for example parse.com

Comment: No I have implemented my own sever for it. Do you need any other information related to server?

Comment: Yeah. If you could give us some more info. Also, maybe you could try to consider something like parse. They're free and nearly always deliver. Also give us more info so we can help out :-)

Comment: for Parse Do I would have to manually enter the messages for the push or is there a way to automatically push when and where required?

Comment: What all info do you need for the server. Actually I need to contact my server guy to get the info. Could you provide me the exact info that you need so that I can ask him the same.

Answer (score 0):

Not directly answering your question, but what you asked about in the comments and an alternative. You could use a push-notification service such as [Parse](http://www.parse.com).
They allow you to send Push Notifications to Web, iOS and Android, also offer data storage and backend infrastructure. The best thing about Parse is that they're free. Unless you have one million unique recipients, which is rather hard to accomplish. Parsee allows you tons end Push Notifications in multiple ways, some including automatic messages based on their tables or other events. You can program those in their cloud code. You can do so using their REST API or their Java Script API if you have a website. You could also send from the Push window on their website. 
Setting up is fairly easy. I'll give you the most important links below.

[iOS Quick Start Guide](https://www.parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_push/ios/swift/existing)

[Rest API](https://www.parse.com/docs/rest/guide)

[PHP Guide](https://www.parse.com/docs/php/guide)

Hope that helps, Julian

Answer (score 0):

If you are dependent on APNS then there is no guarantee provided regarding the delivery of the push notification. And regarding sending multiple notifications. Like if you send notification every min then many may not deliver. Else it will. This service is free and many including myself using it on a regular basis. It has been delivered regularly even though apple will not provide any guarantee. i'm using a php script on server side to send push notification. Refer the below link if you want to know how to send a push notification using php. 
[tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1)